# Use of const in strict mode-React native project

Tags: node.js, react-native

Getting this error while initiating react native project im using ubuntu 14.04 i have tried with root access also and updated node version.help to solve the problem

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:266
  const rnPackage = options.version;
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

FYR

```
root@syscon-ThinkCentre-E73:~# node -v
v0.10.25
root@syscon-ThinkCentre-E73:~# nodejs -v
v0.10.25
root@syscon-ThinkCentre-E73:~# npm -v
1.3.10
syscon@syscon-ThinkCentre-E73:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You're using a really old version of Node.js. Updating it should fix it most probably.

Answer (score 0):

You need node >= 4 for latest version of react-native-cli : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/react-native-cli/package.json#L8

You can check the required version in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/package.json